# Polydivisible Pandigital Number in different bases

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, natural-numbers

I was recently working on finding $m$ that has $n$-digit [polydivisible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polydivisible_number) [pandigital](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandigital_number) number $m$ in base $n$. I have found that $n$ can't be odd number and I have proved it. however, for even $n$, I have only checked $n=2,4,6,8,10$ and they are possible. $(m,n)=(10,2),(1230,4),(3210,4),(143250,6),(543210,6),(32541670,8),(52347610,8),(3816547290,10)$

For the bigger even numbers, as it contains a lot of possibilities, I can't do anymore. Is there anyone can find more possible $m$ or the first even $n$ such that there is no $m$? Thanks!

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect the results of the further search – no more such numbers up to $n=36$.

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect that there's also no such number for $n=38$. That's as far as I'll take the computation.

Comment: Point of clarification, why can't $n$ he odd:  In the pandigital number $0$ must come last and the preceding $n-1$ digits perforce sum to $n(n-1)/2$.  But the number formed by those digits is divisible by $n-1$ only if the sum of digits is so, and therefore the factor $n/2$ has to be a whole number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There’s no such number for $n=12$. For $n=14$ there is `9c3a5476b812d0` (with letters standing for the digits above $9$ as usual). There are no further such numbers up to $n=38$. That’s interesting, as [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polydivisible_number) shows that the estimate that about every $n!$-th number is polydivisible works well for ordinary (not necessarily pandigital) polydivisible numbers, and this would suggest that there should on average be $1$ of the numbers you’re looking for for each $n$, independent of $n$, but apparently this is not the case and they are much rarer for larger $n$.

I’m not sure whether you intended your list to be complete; if so, you missed the $8$-digit octal number $56743210$.

[Here’s the code](https://gist.github.com/joriki/d02c135cdbf667277b882cb57f06e09f) I used to find these numbers.